# Multiple characters in Band of Blades

Tags: forged-in-the-dark, band-of-blades

[Band of Blades](https://www.evilhat.com/home/band-of-blades/)' back cover describes a range of different character options. However it is advertised as 4-6 players, and many of the groups of character options have widely varying numbers of options available.

For missions you appear to be selecting from Rookie, Veteran, and five different specialist roles - so seven options.

But for other parts of the games it lists other numbers of options - always less than six. E.g. There are only five Legion roles, there are only three Chosen, and there are only four heritages.

I assume that this means that multiple players are likely to end up playing the same role. Assuming that is accurate, I wanted to ask about how this works in practice, e.g.

If you have two quartermasters is this going to effect game balance? and do the two different quartermasters feel different to each other?

Or alternatively, does someone sit out that part of the game? (Which seems like it would suck)
Or the last alternative I can see, is that you have the rookie playing with the chosen. Which sounds worryingly like playing bob the ice cream truck driver with Captain Marvel.

Comment: Not sure what tags should be used here -- I included blades-in-the-dark so that it had at least one that wasn't wholly novel.

Comment: If the systems are similar enough that expertise is transferable its probably fine, but speaking of new system tags: do you mind giving them a wiki (at least an excerpt)? Having one stops them from being hoovered by the system. (You even earn a little rep for it.)

Comment: @Someone_Evil The systems definitely are similar enough that some questions cross over sensibly - I've taken a quick dash down the Blades in the Dark and Scum and Villainy tags to add the new forged-in-the-dark tag to a few questions based on common mechanics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Band of Blades makes use of troupe play and player metaroles.

To start off with, one of those metaroles is "GM".

> One player will adopt the role of the game master (GM), whose job is to portray the armies of the undead. There is very little character fidelity, which means that on one mission a player may be playing one character, while on another mission, a different player might pick up that same character.
>
> *Band of Blades* p. 3, "The Players"

So when you're looking at everything splitting up, think in terms of there being 3 to 5 non-GM players. **These are hard limits**, both lower and upper - Band of Blades makes fairly strict mechanical assumptions about the aggregate amount of punishment inflicted over the course of a typical mission, which shouldn't be spread too thick or too thin, and even 5 non-GM players are called out as a special exception needing slightly unusual handling at the end of the book. (p.437)

And that "little character fidelity" has been called "troupe play" elsewhere - the term has existed at least as far back as *Ars Magica*. There are a large number of available characters to play, more are created as needed, and who plays a character can change from session to session.

Each of those 3-5 players will create one starting Specialist, each from a different archetype, but actual gameplay might involve different characters entirely.

A **primary mission**, for instance, goes like this:

> The Marshal will assign a squad and up to two Specialists to [the] mission. [...]
>
> It's not essential that the same character be played by the same player each time, though that may be how your table prefers to do it. Other players will play available Rookies or Soldiers in the squad the Specialists are sent alongside of. Grab a blank Rookie or Soldier playbook if you need to detail someone new.
>
> -- *Band of Blades* p.217, "Choosing Characters and Load"

**Heritages** influence character-based gameplay - they're the four primary cultures among the members of the Legion, offering a selection of small additional bonuses and play guidelines to the larger playbooks. They're not mutually exclusive the way Specialist playbooks are.

In addition to character-based gameplay in missions, each player takes responsibility for monitoring some aspect of the Legion **outside squad missions**:

> Each player, including the GM, takes on a Role that divides up the responsibilities of the game so that it's manageable for the group. [...] Each Legion Role is also a character - one of the leaders in the Legion's command staff.
>
> -- *Band of Blades* p. 113, "The Legion"

The three required roles are the Commander, who tracks Legion progress through the campaign and picks missions to do; the Marshal, who assigns squads and Specialists to the missions; and the Quartermaster, who manages overall supply and between-mission actions like recovery or long-term projects. But these and the two other optional Legion Roles aren't big-c Characters who have stats and action ratings; they're people in the story, but to the extent that the outcome of their actions is directly in doubt it's decided more by Legion-wide statistics like Intel, Morale, and Materiel.

So, the non-GM players play Specialists and squaddies on missions, and take responsibility for a Legion Role outside of missions (though free-play scenes back at camp might also involve the character-sheet characters). What's the Chosen for, then?

**The Chosen is a Legion character run by the GM:**

> The final decision on the Chosen falls to the GM. [...] Often we focus on a squad handling the main objective while the Chosen, represented by clocks, distracts and battles a powerful undead.
>
> *Band of Blades* pp. 160-163, "The Divine"

It's a bit like the PCs' crew in *Blades in the Dark*. The PCs don't dictate the personalities and actions of each subordinate member of their crew, at least not with the level of focus and control that they do with the individual scoundrels, but the crew as a whole offers benefits to all the PCs and shapes the sorts of scores the PCs might decide to take.

The Chosen is an inversion of that - a superordinate member of the Legion with tremendous individual power that the PC Specialists and squaddies work with, for, and occasionally around. To the extent that mission or camp action involves them, the GM plays them and the player-visible portion of their powers comes out in clocks and fortune rolls.